# Number of lines added and deleted in a git repository using python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

The following code prints the files which have been modified in current tree vs previous tree (if changed):

```
for modified in commit.diff('HEAD~1').iter_change_type('M'):                         
    print(modified.a_blob.path)      # prints all files modified
```

How to get number of lines added and deleted too?
(Just like we do using git log --numstat).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @AkhilSinghal thank you for accepting my answer.  My suggestion was that you open a _new_ question regarding the formatting issue rather than changing your existing question to a different one.

Comment: @MattMorgan Ok, I will. Thanks btw for guiding me.

Comment: No problem man.  Happy to help when I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use git directly to do this from within `gitpython`:

```
the_git = repo.git
log = the_git.log('--numstat')
```

More here if you like: http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly

Comment: You should be executing this code in a context where `repo` is defined.  I (mistakenly) assumed you understood that, since you would have needed that to have your above code working.  If you want to post a more complete example I can try to help more.

Comment: **Update**-This did the work I was looking for. But the format of output is a single string of the form: **num(added)** **num(deleted)** **file-name** for all files which requires huge string manipulation to extract out the useful data. Can this output format of diff be somehow manipulated/changed, like list of lists or something else?

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  I'm sure the output could be changed, but that seems like a different question.  You asked how to reproduce `git log --numstat`, which is what my answer does.  Please ask about formatting as a separate question, and I or someone else would be happy to help!  Since this answer does satisfy your original post, please accept it if you would.